# Not able to write Message into file using Kotlin

Tags: android, file, android-studio, kotlin

I am using kotlin language in my project. I used below code and code throws me no error but I am getting file not found exception in the log message.

```
var a="Hello"

WriteToFile(a)

    fun WriteToFile(message: String)
    {
        try {
            var writer=FileWriter("message.txt")
            writer.write(message)
            writer.close()
        }
        catch (ex: Exception)
        {
            println("Exception $ex")
        }
    }
```

**Error**

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: message.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Have you added the permission ` < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ` in Manifest.xml?

Comment: Also do writer.flush() before write.close()

Comment: @ankuranurag2 I'm new to Kotlin, but in many languages the buffer flushes when the destructor is called, isn't this the case in Kotlin as well? What I mean by this is that when we call `writer.close()`, the buffer is flushed automatically before closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, maybe it doesn't have permissions to create the file in the current directory, you can specify an absolute location you know for sure it'll work. Also as a suggestion, if you are targeting the **JVM**, you could utilize the [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html%5C) function.

**Example**

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    writeToFile("Hello, World!!!")
}

fun writeToFile(message: String) {
    FileWriter("/Users/omainegra/Desktop/message.txt").use { writer ->
        try {
            writer.write(message)
        }
        catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Also, I'd like to mention that if you only need to write an `String` to the **File**, it can be easily done with `File("message.txt").writeText(message)`

Comment: Thanks @Omar for your comment but still I am getting the same error. I am using windows so, Do I need to change / to \ in my path ?

Comment: `java.nio.Files` is a better option though; see http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks